# In ionic, I want get the firestore doc id

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

In ionic, I want to get the firestore document id to display the stored information of the user who logged in. I set the documents name to the user's email like **Collection**[name] **= User**  **Document**[name] = **user@zzzz.zz**

Here is how i set the document name in **auth.ts**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {}

registerUser(value){

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)

    this.firestore.doc(`users/${value.email}`).set({
      email: value.email,
    })
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
   }
```

**In home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>
  users: Observable<any[]>;

ngOnInit() {
     this.usersCollection.doc(How do I get the user's email which is stored as 
     document name here)
}
```

**In home.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of info">
<h1>{{item.Name}}</h1>
</div>
```

I tried this but of course it didn't work

```
this.usersCollection.doc(`${this.auth.user}`).ref.get()
```

How to get and add the user's doc name which is their logged in email address

Comment: I strongly suggest not using an email address as a document ID.  It's easier to use the UID of the created used, as that string will always be a valid document ID.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the suggestion

Comment: but how to get the uid @DougStevenson

Answer (score 0):

Getting Current user Uid:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth'

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth){

           let uid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid
}
```

Comment: this error pops ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
    at new HomePage (home.page.ts:33)

Answer (score 0):

Import :

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

To get current user :

```
 var result=  firebase.auth().currentUser; //add .uid if you want
```

[Current user Info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

To get the current user sign in , you can store his email  in storage  and after you call your service like this :

```
getUserById(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   this.usersCollection.doc<User>(id).valueChanges().subscribe((value:User)=> {
     value.id=id;
      resolve(value)
    });
  });
}
```

id is the email  you have in your storage.

Comment: but how do i retrieve data from firestore  with this

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined

Comment: ngOnInit(){

    var ib = this.firestore.doc(`users/${firebase.auth().currentUser}`).snapshotChanges();
    this.loki = ib.subscribe(data => {
      return {
        Name: data.payload.data()['Name'],
      };});
    console.log(this.loki);

Comment: got this error core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (home.page.ts:49)